# Connecting 3-pin buzzer to 4 pin System warning speaker

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power-supply, asus, beep-code

I am trying to connect a three-pin [Buzzer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7M0F.jpg) to my [Motherboard system warning speaker pins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SgLw.png) to hear the beep codes. I connected the VCC to +5V and GND to GND on the motherboard. I am not sure if this is correct since I do not hear anything. The problem I am trying to solve is that my PC fans and cooler LEDs are running, however there is no signal on the monitor or keyboard.

Comment: You need to connect `I/O` on the discrete board to `Speaker` on the motherboard header.

Comment: You need a 2-wire buzzer, as shown in [How to Connect Internal Motherboard Speaker?](https://pcguide101.com/motherboard/how-to-connect-internal-motherboard-speaker/). The GND pins are not used.

Comment: @spikey_richie I did. https://imgur.com/a/Yi1FoCW. However, I still don't hear anything.

Comment: @AndrewMorton So this one cannot be used?

Comment: @Ershad The only way to be sure would be examine its circuit diagram, but if you're trying to fault-find, you don't want to add something else that you are not sure of the behaviour of. Maybe your PC case came with a 2-pin buzzer and it's still in the accessories bag.

Comment: @Ershad Check your mobo manual. Usually the 4 pin speaker connector ha only two pins which are connected on the board (first, last), the others two in the middle are just electrical dummies that are connected to nothing.